# Можно ли с помощью циклов sass найти определённый элемент в html и применить стили только к нему?

Tags: css, sass

У меня есть 4 карточки в html в каждой есть картинка и последней карточки я  хочу написать стили не как у остальных.  Хочу узнать возможно ли с помощью циклов sass найти этот элемент и пременить стили только к нему?

Таких четыре карточки:

```
<div class="cooperation_causes cooperation_causes-4">
   <h3 class="cooperation_causes-title">В сроки сдаем работу!</h3>
   <p class="cooperation_causes-sub">Расписываем каждый этап по срокам, и придерживаемся дедлайнов</p>
   <img src="../images/cooperation_icons/time.png" alt="image" class="cooperation_images"> Нужно применить стили только к этой картинке
</div>
```

Конечно можно написать ей доп. класс, но я хотел узнать возможно ли сделать это элегантнее с  помощью sass)

Comment: Для этого есть [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)